# Random Obstacle Generator in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking to make my first actual game called Bottomless. It seems I am having a problem with the obstacle generator script in Unity2D. I want the obstacle to generate vertically, where a player is falling down the level.

Here my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spike;
    public float maxspeed;
    public float minspeed;
    public float currentspeed;

    void Awake()
    {
        currentspeed = Random.Range(maxspeed, minspeed);
        spikegen();
    }

    void spikegen()
    {
        GameObject SpikeIns = Instantiate(spike, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Seems like running this code crashes unity quickly. Does anyone have better alternative?

Comment: Honestly, just from looking at the code here it seems fine. When you say it crashes Unity, what do you mean? Nothing here should crash unity. If you would like to change the code, you could always use a coroutine that gets called in the Awake function.

Comment: The unity (While pressing the play button) Just Quit.  My theory is that it creates a bunch of Obstacles and stresses out the unity which then quits. Any way to handle number of clones

Comment: Well it appears to only be called once, so it should only create one clone. Are you calling this code somewhere else? In Update or another function? I see from your post that you want the spikes to generate when the player is falling, how is this accomplished? Are you calling the instantiate at certain time intervals? Or when the player reaches a certain position?

Comment: Was just thinking, if the player is falling you must be generating the map he is falling through. If so, then you could also pre-place the spikes in the map parts when you are designing them. But if you are after a certain level of randomness, that will not do.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have been considering your problem, and I think the best thing to do would be to create spawn points in your map pieces for the spikes to fit in. Then, when your player is falling, and the new map is loaded, grab the spawn points, add them to a list, choose one randomly, and then instantiate your spike there. Or get the map pieces themselves to spawn the spikes as they are loaded.

Method 1:

Create spawn points on your map piece. Create and add the following script. Place the spawn points in the list in inspector. And call function on Awake/Start.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class MapScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Spike you want to instantiate
    public GameObject spike;
    //List for you to place spawn points in the inspector
    public List<GameObject> Spawnpoints = new List<GameObject>();

    public void Awake()
    {
      //Get a random number from 0 to our lists count
      int random = Random.Range(0, Spawnpoints.Count);

      //Instantiate at the random spawn point
      GameObject SpikeIns = Instantiate(spike, Spawnpoints[random].transform.position, transform.rotation);
    
    }
     
}
```

Method 2:

Similar to the example above, except the code to spawn happens in the Generator script (this is not the preferred method as we will have to access the map piece's script).

So use the code above but remove the Awake and spike GameObject, and then for your generator script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spike;
    public float maxspeed;
    public float minspeed;
    public float currentspeed;

    void Awake()
    {
        currentspeed = Random.Range(maxspeed, minspeed);
        spikegen();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void spikegen()
    {
        List<GameObject> Spawners = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach(GameObject spawn in refernceToOtherScripts.Spawnpoints)
        {
          Spawners.Add(spawn);
        }
        
        int random = Random.Range(0, Spawners.Count);
        GameObject SpikeIns = Instantiate(spike, Spawners[random].transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
    
}
```

Neither of these have been tested as I am on my work computer, but they should both work perfectly fine. As you have probably guessed, there are a lot of different way to go about this.